# Simplifying this rational expression into simplest form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The expression: $\frac{5(x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 - 2xy + y^2} $

I factored the polynomial at the top, and got this:
$\frac{5(x - y)(x+y)}{x^2 - 2xy + y^2} $

This is how far I've gone... how should I factor the bottom? I need some brushing up since I'm not very good at factoring!

Comment: There's quite a well-known factorisation for the bottom too.

Comment: If you don't "see" the factorization of the denominator upfront, why not use the work you did on the numerator, and check whether either $x-y$ or $x+y$ is a factor. One of them will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can factor the bottom:

$$x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$$

Remember that:

$$(a\pm b)^2=a^2\pm2ab+b^2$$

Comment: @JennyB It's is know that $(a-b)^2$ follows the form $a^2-2ab+b^2$. But instead of memorizing blindly, you already know either $x-y$ or $x+y$. Then you can try either to see if it factors. Your other factor tools apply here, (what two things multiply to $y^2$ but produce a negative term $-2xy$, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{5(x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 - 2xy + y^2} = \frac{5(x^2 - y^2)}{(x-y)^2}=$$

$$\frac{5(x- y)(x+y)}{(x-y)(x-y)}=\frac{5(x+y)}{(x-y)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the quadratic equation for $x$:
$$\begin{align} x^2-2yx+y^2=0 \\ x_{1,2}=&\frac{\left(-\frac{b}{2}\right)\pm \sqrt{\left(-\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-ac}}{a}= \\
&\frac{\left(-\frac{-2y}{2}\right)\pm \sqrt{\left(-\frac{-2y}{2}\right)^2-1\cdot y^2}}{1}= \\
&y \Rightarrow \end{align} \\
x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)(x-y).$$
Alternatively, you can guess the roots of the quadratics:
$$x^2-2yx+y^2=(x-a)(x-b) \Rightarrow \begin{cases} ab=y^2 \\ a+b=2y\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} a=y \\ b=y \end{cases}.$$